# Update existing table row in the same method that uses HttpPost to add a new entry

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a web game that uses .NetCore Entity Framework.

I have one method that uses HttpPost to create a new Monster in the database.

This method also needs to add a foreign key, the new MonsterId, to an existing Dungeon in the table called DungeonList.

I got the part where the method creates a new Monster correctly.

However I'm not sure how to insert the new MonsterId into the appropriate Dungeon of DungeonList.

I'm not exactly sure how to get the Id of the Dungeon.

Should I pass in the DungeonId from the frontend?

I'm really confused.

Here is what I have so far but I am not sure where to go from here.

I'd love some advice...thank you!

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MonsterList>> PostMonsterList(MonsterList monsterList)
    {
        monsterList.MonsterId = Guid.NewGuid();

        _context.MonsterList.Add(monsterList);

        var dungeonListRef = new DungeonList();

        if(dungeonListRef.MonsterId == null)
        {
            // ????
        }


        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (MonsterListExists(monsterList.MonsterId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        _context.DungeonList.Add(dungeonListRef);

        return CreatedAtAction("GetMonsterList", new { id = monsterList.MonsterId }, monsterList);
    }
```

Comment: What's the relationship between DungeonList and MonsterList, can you show us the two class. I think it may be better define a foreign key called DungeonId  in MonsterList class. Then when you save a new Monster, it will automatically pointed to the corresponding Dungeon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Dungeon drop down list in your "Add new Monster" page. Send drop down list's dungeonID to PostMonsterList function.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<MonsterList>> PostMonsterList(Guid dungeonId, MonsterList monsterList)
{
     Guid newMonsterId = Guid.NewGuid();
     monsterList.MonsterId = newMonsterId;
     _context.MonsterList.Add(monsterList);
     try
     {
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException)
     {
         if (MonsterListExists(monsterList.MonsterId))
         {
             return Conflict();
         }
         else
         {
             throw;
         }
     }
     var dungeonList = _context.DungeonList.Where(x => x.DungeonId == dungeonId).FirstOrDefault();
     dungeonList.MonsterId = newMonsterId;
     _context.DungeonList.Update(dungeonList);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return CreatedAtAction("GetMonsterList", new { id = monsterList.MonsterId }, monsterList);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! So the web page that handles this already knows about the dungeonId.  So instead of creating a new user control drop down, can I just pass in the dungeonId to my controller?

Comment: Yes, can pass it to your controller.